# after install hhvm , find no folder of hhvm in /usr/share folder

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, hhvm

After install nginx and hhvm , in /usr/share folder can not find any hhvm folder so I can not run this command "sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh" get an error : sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please any help ..

Answer (score 0):

Please could you provide any details about your install process? I've just made an installation via ubuntu packages and I can find that file on my PC

```
ls -lrth /usr/share/hhvm/
total 16K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4,5K jul 19 20:02 uninstall_fastcgi.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5,6K jul 19 20:02 install_fastcgi.sh
```

The command to install hhvm on a Ubuntu distro is below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm
```

Hope it helps. Best regards. 
Javi

Comment: Thanks for your reply . It is done now . I changed ubuntu 18.04 to 16.04 , after that no problem occured .